# Error while reindexing using cron

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex

Cron job failed to

### reindex

we have to index the data manually.

**job_code** : `indexer_reindex_all_invalid`

**status** : `error`

**messages** : `Error when running a cron job`

Comment: is this the only message which is available? can you please check exception.log and system.log if there is something which helpful to identify the error

Comment: @RakeshVarma [2021-03-26 05:18:52] report.CRITICAL: Error when running a cron job {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Error when running a cron job at /vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:330, TypeError(code: 0): current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given at /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php:61)"} []

Comment: I have fixed this error but the issue is existed

Comment: [2021-03-26 05:19:26] report.INFO: ApiHelper::isResponseValid (info): Response is not valid for getProductWithRef - Error: You must be authorized to view this page. - Error code: 401 [] []

Answer (score 0):

[2021-03-26 05:17:29] report.CRITICAL: The requested sku is not assigned to given stock. [] []

https://github.com/magento/inventory/blob/1.2-develop/InventoryShippingAdminUi/Model/IsOrderSourceManageable.php#L78